# Solving $\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{k+1} = \frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}$ combinatorially?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, combinatorial-proofs

I have solved  $\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{k+1} = \frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}$ using integrals as follows: $$(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k.$$$$\frac{(2)^{n+1}}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{1^{k+1}}{k+1}$$$$\frac{(2)^{n+1} - 1}{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{k+1} $$ (set x = 1)

However, the question states at the end "Can you also find a combinatorial proof for this identity?" I belive the answer is yes, but I am having trouble going about showing it.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1847474) for a combinatorial argument. Also, consider using [Approach0](https://www.approach0.xyz) for searching for mathematical expressions on this site. It'll save you time , particularly if you're taking a combinatorics course.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4505277/177399) rephrases the elegant probabilistic proof above as a combinatorial proof.